# Can't modify object vector in a class

Tags: c++, function, c++11, vector, constructor

I'm trying to access an object in my vector and change some attributes, but it doesn't modify it. (Sorry for french code)

```
 class Quincaillerie
 {
    vector<Caisse> vCaisses;
    public:
    Quincaillerie(int NBCaisse);
    vector<Caisse> GetCaisses() const { return vCaisses; }
 };
```

Here's the vector vCaisses that I want to access and change

```
class Caisse
{
    int tempsFile;
    public:
    Caisse();
    int GetTempsFile() const { return tempsFile; }
    void AjouterTempsFile(int t) { tempsFile = t; }
};
```

Here's the class

```
Caisse::Caisse() : tempsFile(0)
{
} 

Quincaillerie::Quincaillerie(int NBCaisse) : vCaisses(NBCaisse, Caisse())
{
}
```

Now when I tried to do this

```
int main()
{
    Quincaillerie Magasin(NBCAISSES);
    /****Here's the problem****/
    Magasin.GetCaisses().at(0).AjouterTempsFile(100);
    cout << Magasin.GetCaisses().at(0).GetTempsFile() << endl;
    /****Does not work****/
}
```

It's suppose to cout 100, but cout 0

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try returning a `vector<Caisse> &` from `GetCaisses()` instead of `vector<Caisse>`.

If your `GetCaisses()` returns a `vector<Caisse>` *by value*, only a **copy** of the `vCaisses` in the object instance is returned.

So you modify one copy and then query another copy that isn't modified.

You should write a second `GetCaisses()` that isn't `const` if you want to modify the returned value; something like

```
const vector<Caisse> & GetCaisses() const
 { return vCaisses; }

vector<Caisse> & GetCaisses()
 { return vCaisses; }
```

In this way, `GetCaisses()` methods return **a reference** to `vCaisees` and you can modify it (if you modify the vector received from the not const version).